# Finding pairs of repeating entries

Tags: sql, group-by, duplicates

Could you please help me with one SQL query?

Table : Students

```
Id | Name | Date of birth
1    Will   1991-02-10
2    James  1981-01-20
3    Sam    1991-02-10
```

I need to find pairs of students who has same Date of birth. However, **we are not allowed to use GROUP BY**, so simply grouping and counting records is not a solution.

I have been trying to do it with JOIN, however with no success.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self join on the table, joining on the `date_of_birth` column:

```
select s1.name,
       s2.name
from students s1
  join students s2 
    on s1.date_of_birth = s2.date_of_birth
   and s1.name < s2.name;
```

As wildplasser and  dasblinkenlight pointed out the `<` operator (or `>`) is better than a `<>` because when using `<>` in the join condition, the combination Will/Sam will be reported twice.

Another way of removing duplicate those duplicates is to use a distinct query:

```
select distinct greatest(s1.name, s2.name), least(s1.name, s2.name)
from students s1
  join students s2 
    on s1.date_of_birth = s2.date_of_birth
   and s1.name <> s2.name;
```

(although eliminating the duplicates in the join condition is almost certainly more efficient)

Comment: `and s1.name < s2.name;` to suppress twins being reported twice?

Comment: +1 I would also replace `s1.name <> s2.name` with `s1.name > s2.name` to avoid bringing each pair twice

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks a lot, this worked! I was building same query, but without `s1.name < s2.name` condition - I haven't thought about this way to filter duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

This query reports all students who have a non-unique birthdate.

```
SELECT *
FROM students s
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM students ex
    WHERE ex.dob = st.dob
    AND ex.name <> st.name
    )
ORDER BY dob
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select st.name, stu.name
from students st, students stu
where st.date_of_birth = stu.date_of_birth AND and st.name <> stu.name;
```